# Replacing specific characters in python string

Tags: python, string, text

I have a string which is

`string = "create (:TestCustomer {'FIRSTNAME': 'James', 'LASTNAME': 'Comey', 'CITY': 'Sydney'})"`

I want to replace specific set of `'` to `%`. It has to look like

```
string = "create (:TestCustomer {%FIRSTNAME%: 'James', %LASTNAME%: 'Comey', %CITY%: 'Sydney'})"
```

I'm trying to use replace function. But failed to get the exact result.

Comment: Could you be more specific on how you are trying to replace. Is it something like `'` for CAPS is replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"'([^']+)': '([^']*)'", r"%\1%: '\2'", string)
"create (:TestCustomer {%FIRSTNAME%: 'James', %LASTNAME%: 'Comey', %CITY%: 'Sydney'})"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `re` to replace patterns.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "create (:TestCustomer {'FIRSTNAME': 'James', 'LASTNAME': 'Comey', 'CITY': 'Sydney'})"
>>> S=re.sub(r"\'([A-Z]*)\'",r"%\1%",s)
create (:TestCustomer {%FIRSTNAME%: 'James', %LASTNAME%: 'Comey', %CITY%: 'Sydney'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "create (:TestCustomer {'FIRSTNAME': 'James', 'LASTNAME': 'Comey', 'CITY': 'Sydney'})"

w = string.find('{')+ 1
x = w + 10;t = w + 22;y = w + 31;z = w + 43;q = w + 48
w1=string[w].replace("'",'%')
x1=string[x].replace("'",'%')
t1=string[t].replace("'",'%')
y1=string[y].replace("'",'%')
z1=string[z].replace("'",'%')
q1=string[q].replace("'",'%')

print(string[0:23]+w1+string[24:33]+x1+string[34:45]+t1+string[46:54]+y1+string[55:66]+z1+string[67:71]+q1+string[72:])
```

hope that is what you wanted.